# SQL IN statement doesn't work with comma separated values

Tags: sql, db2

I'm running my query and trying to get orders from table B which are included in orders list in table A.
I'm getting results only if orders list have only one element

```
select *
from A,B
where substr(B.order,6,1) in A.orders
```

[image: Table A]
[image: Table B]
[image: Result]

Comment: Format your sample data properly so it's readable.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values to begin with. That is a really, really bad idea. The problem you have at hand is just one example on why that is such a bad idea

Comment: What way to you suggest me to store orders for Table A?

Comment: TABLE(VALUES (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,3),(2,5),(2,6),(3,2),(2,4),(4,5)) AS A("id", "orders")

Answer (score 1):

You need a proper `join` of the tables and the `like` operator:

```
select A.id, B.order
from A inner join B
on ',' || A.orders || ',' like '%,' || substr(B.order,6,1) || ',%'
```

Note: I think DB2 supports the `||` operator for concatenation.
If not:

```
select A.id, B.order
from A inner join B
on concat(concat(',', A.orders), ',') like concat(concat('%,', substr(B.order,6,1)), ',%')
```

Note: `substr(B.order,6,1)` will return 1 char from `B.order`, but if you have numbers greater than `9` then you should use:

```
substr(B.order,6)
```

this returns all the chars starting from the 6th position up to the end of `B.order`

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertStringToTable] (@String_IN VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @Temp TABLE
   (id int not null)
AS
BEGIN
    ;-- Ensure input ends with comma
    SET @String_IN = REPLACE(@String_IN + ',', ',,', ',')
    DECLARE @Place INT
    DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX('%,%', @String_IN ) <> 0 
BEGIN
   SELECT  @Place = PATINDEX('%,%',@String_IN)
   SELECT  @VALUE = LEFT(@String_IN , @Place - 1)
   SELECT  @String_IN = STUFF(@String_IN, 1, @Place, '')
   INSERT INTO @Temp(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

To use the function

```
SELECT a.id, b.order
   FROM a,b 
   WHERE substr(b.order,6,1) IN (SELECT * FROM [MillWorks].[ConvertStringToTable]          (a.orders) )
```

Results:
1   order1
1   order2
1   order3
1   order4
1   order5
2   order3
2   order5
2   order6
3   order2
3   order4
4   order5